# Merge two vectors by non NA values

Tags: r, vector, na

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining two vectors element-by-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511476/combining-two-vectors-element-by-element)

I have two vectors

```
d = c(1, 2, NA, NA)
c = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)
```

How can I get an output that would combine the non NAs as follows?

```
[1] 1 2  1 NA
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking is a bit vague. For example, what happens if you neither element is a NA?

Anyway, here's one method that gives the desired result:

```
##Don't name things c - it's confusing.
d1 = c(1,2,NA,NA)
d2 = c(NA,NA,1,NA)

d1[is.na(d1)] = d2[is.na(d1)]
```

Which gives:

```
R> d1
[1]  1  2  1 NA
```

Comment: thanks, nice and simple solution. (I don't have values where both elements are non NAs).

Answer (score 15):

```
pmin(d, c, na.rm = TRUE)
```

will do the trick.

```
[1]  1  2  1 NA
```