# Match Vector to multiple columns, return index and corresponding value in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a dataframe:

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 9) 
b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 10) 
c = c('xx','yy','zz', 'kk', 'bb') 
df = data.frame(a, b, c) 

> df
  a  b  c
1 1  5 xx
2 2  6 yy
3 3  7 zz
4 4  8 kk
5 9 10 bb
```

And an integer vector:

```
> names
[1] 1 3 5 8
Levels: 1 3 5 8
```

I can return the index in `df` where `names` matches column `a` or `b`, using `match`:

```
> match(names, df$a)
[1]  1  3 NA NA
> match(names, df$b)
[1] NA NA  1  4
```

I want to combine the above two statements, and for the indexes returned, return the corresponding value in column c, for that particular index, so that my output is:

```
out = [1] "xx" "zz" "xx" "kk"
```

I tried to do:

```
> df$c[match(names, df$a) | match(names, df$b)]
[1] "xx" "yy" "zz" "kk" "bb"
```

But as this becomes a boolean test, it does not function as required.

How can I achieve my desired output? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `c` and specifying `nomatch = 0`

```
df$c[c(match(names, df$a, nomatch = 0), match(names, df$b, nomatch=0))]
#[1] xx zz xx kk
#Levels: bb kk xx yy zz
```

Wrap it with `as.character` if we want it as `character` class

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This represents a simple version of my data. In my real data, when I run this command, I end up with lots of zeros, where instead there should be a value, e.g. `c(match(names, df$a, nomatch = 0))` gives `[1]   0   0   0   0   0 116   0`, `c(match(names, df$b, nomatch=0))` gives `[1] 247  87  40 335 220   0 227` and together, `c(match(names, df$a, nomatch = 0), match(names, df$b, nomatch=0))` gives `[1]   0   0   0   0   0 116   0` Any idea why the 0s don't get replaced with value from the other match case?

Comment: @ChuckM in R index starts from 0.  Even if there are 0's it is not used

Comment: Ok. But it means that the dataframe subset takes 0's instead of taking the value, i.e. instead of it getting `df$c[247 87 40 335 220 116 227]` it gets `df$c[0 0 0 0 0 116 0 247 87 40 335 220 0 227]` which is not correct. Currently, this way sort of appends the `b` indexes to the end of the `a` indexes, rather than slicing them together as I need. Is it possible to preserve the order and auto remove 0's?

Comment: Thanks, I found how to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511476/combining-two-vectors-element-by-element. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df$c[c(which(df$a %in% names) , which(df$b %in% names))]

# [1] xx zz xx kk
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try on my bigger data set and see how it works.